# Как определить, что поле формы сейчас редактируется (js/php)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, angularjs

Как определить и вывести, что поля в форме редактируется(как пример редактирование статьи) в данный момент и кем.
т.е. один - правит статью в админке, а второй заходит редактировать ту же статью и видит, что в данный момент что-то редактируется и кем.
Может есть какие-то уже готовые скрипты или .... или ... 
А то не пойму, куда копать. Спасибо.

---

Думаю может манипулировать hidden полями.

Comment: типа как GoogleDocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы решал эту проблему так:
 1. Повешал бы наблюдателя на поле.
 2. И при каждом изменении слал был данные на сервер.

Соотвественно уже на сервере следил бы, кто какое поле редактировал. Сравнивал и возвращал бы это клиентам. Но тут всплывает множество подводных камней.

По поводу готовых плагинов не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо. Выберу данный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Создаете флаг `edited` который равен 0 или 1. Если нажали на кнопку эдит, ставить `edited=1`. 
Ставите проверку перед эдит, если `edited!=1` только тогда открыть эдит. 
Кнопкой сохранить ставите `edited=0`.
Таким оброзом создаете проверку если уже кто-то редакторует статью

Comment: Можно одним выстрелом убить двух зайцев и в поле вместо 1 ставить id юзера, который открыл текущий файл для редактирования. В итоге если 0, то есть возможность редактирования, если нет, то показано какой пользователь в данный момент работает с документом